# How to ignore certain HTML rows in a JS search function

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a simple JS search function that goes like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2], [3];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";;
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have certain rows with the class 'day' which I want to include for any search function. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome. At the line "td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2],[3];" you likely get a set returned. You need to iterate the set. Currently you are ignoring this. Regarding applying to the 'day' class, get this current code working and it should be simple to make it into a function and pass in the class to scan.

Comment: A bit less code to write `tr = table.rows` and `td = tr[i].cells[2]`. ;-)